# Use interval_selection from one dataset/chart to filter data in another dataset/chart

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I have two dataframes with seperate data that cannot be joined. I would like to create two charts, and use an `interval_selection` on one to filter data-points in the other. Below is my attempt to do so:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd 

brush = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-06']),
    'x_value': [1., 2., 4., 3., 5.],
    'y_value': [4., 3., 2., 5., 1.],
})
other_data = pd.DataFrame({'date_col': pd.to_datetime([f'2022-01-0{i}' for i in range(1, 10)])})

scatter = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='x_value:Q',
    y='y_value:Q',
).transform_filter(
    (alt.datum.date >= brush.x[0]) & (alt.datum.date <= brush.x[1])  # does not work
)

scatter2 = alt.Chart(other_data).mark_point().encode(x='date_col:T').add_selection(brush)

scatter & scatter2
```

Ideally, the code above should allow me to filter data pointers in `scatter` based on the date-range selected in `scatter2`. However, this plot does not render at all (the problematic line is indicated via a comment). How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To filter on a brush, you don't need to make a comparison; it will be treated as a mask when passed to `transform_filter`.

You also need the same column name that is on the x-axis in the selection chart to be present as some type of encoding in the other chart as well. You can use `detail` if you don't want it to be mapped to a visual attribute (I also added shape below for clarity).

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd 


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-06']),
    'x_value': [1., 2., 4., 3., 5.],
    'y_value': [4., 3., 2., 5., 1.],
})
other_data = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime([f'2022-01-0{i}' for i in range(1, 10)])})


brush = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])

scatter = alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=200, filled=True).encode(
    x='x_value:Q',
    y='y_value:Q',
    shape='date(date):N',
    detail='date'
).transform_filter(
    brush
)

scatter2 = alt.Chart(other_data).mark_point().encode(x='date').add_selection(brush)

scatter & scatter2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful work-around! Is there any way to make the expr work without changing column names? In my actual use case, I have a start and end date that I want to filter using the brush (i.e. `(alt.datum.start_date >= brush.x[0]) & (alt.datum.end_date <= brush.x[1])`).